# Fabric.js beta2 – text underline options

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How can we exactly get and set the underline, overline etc. properties now for text, iText and Textbox in the 2.x beta? Is there some documentation available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var text = new fabric.Text('FabricJS is Awsome.',{
 fontSize:'30',
 left:50,
 top:50,
 underline:true
});
canvas.add(text);
//text.setSelectionStyles({overline:true},0,5);
canvas.renderAll();
function changeStyle(val){
 text[val] = !text[val];
 text.dirty = true;
 canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick=changeStyle('underline')>underline</button>
<button onclick=changeStyle('overline')>overline</button>
<button onclick=changeStyle('linethrough')>linethrough</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Same as other property set/get from object. [fabric.Text](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html)

Comment: @SandorRozsa upvote and mark if this what you wanted. Cheers ;)

Comment: sorry durga – missed doing that... :-)